# Customize WordPress Editor

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry if my terminology is confusing but I am unsure of what call this exactly.

In Wordpress when editing a post or page type, on the right side of the editor there is the sections Publish, Attributes, Featured Image, etc. I'm wondering if there is a way where I can add my own section to the right side like the other? Is it custom post type or something more complicated?

I'm trying to stay within the possiblity of using hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are 'meta boxes'

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

```
function my_custom_meta_boxes()
{
  add_meta_box(
    'custom1', // id
    'Custom Metabox', // title
    'display_custom_meta_box', // callback for display
    'post', // post type
    'normal', // position
    'high' // priority
  );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_custom_meta_boxes');

function display_custom_meta_box()
{
  echo 'Your meta box here';
}
```

There are plugins available to create meta boxes quickly e.g.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meta-box/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Read up about it here^
Wasn't that hard to google! :)

Comment: It wasn't hard to google the answer I wasn't looking for. I'm asking to modify the editor(the page with the WYSWIG), now page templates.